# SQL Select Max of ID Value only

Tags: sql

I've been hitting a wall trying to figure out how to select only the most recent date values

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.StockStatusHistory.StockID AS Expr1, 
    dbo.Stock.StockNo, dbo.CardFile.CardName AS SalesPerson, 
    dbo.Stock.Description, dbo.Stock.Retail, 
    dbo.Stock.SaleOrderDate, dbo.Stock.WarrantyStartDate, dbo.Stock.SaleNotes, 
    dbo.Stock.ManuMonth, dbo.Stock.ManuYear, dbo.Stock.InspCertDate, 
    dbo.Stock.StockStatus, dbo.StockStatusHistory.NewStockStatus, 
    dbo.StockStatusHistory.ChangeDate AS Expr2, 
    dbo.StockStatusHistory.ID, dbo.CardFile.CardId, 
    dbo.Stock.SalesPersonId
FROM
    dbo.Stock 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CardFile ON dbo.Stock.SalesPersonId = dbo.CardFile.CardId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StockStatusHistory ON dbo.Stock.StockId = dbo.StockStatusHistory.StockID
WHERE     
    (dbo.Stock.StockStatus = 30) AND (dbo.Stock.WarrantyStartDate >= { fn CURDATE() }) 
    AND (dbo.StockStatusHistory.NewStockStatus = 30) 
    OR (dbo.Stock.StockStatus = 30) AND (dbo.Stock.WarrantyStartDate IS NULL) 
    AND (dbo.StockStatusHistory.NewStockStatus = 30)
```

I tried to use `MAX(dbo.StockStatusHistory.StockID)` but I came up with errors.

Hope my code makes sense. Quite new to SQL queries obviously.

Thanks in advance
Andy

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean by "most recent date values", but I assume that you want the newest entries based on a date field somewhere.

It's difficult to say without the schema at hand, but you could create an `ORDER BY MyDate DESC` at the end and a `SELECT TOP 1 dbo.xxx` in the beginning.